# [openGauss]Please use "ALTER ROLE "user" PASSWORD 'password';" to set the password of the user before other operations

Tags: open-gauss

The system prompts me to change the password each time the openGauss database is installed.
To initialize the openGauss database, my steps as follows:

step1:
gs_initdb -D /data2/openGauss/install --nodename='datanode'

step2：
gaussdb -D /data2/openGauss/install --single_node -p 12300 &

step3:
gsql -d postgres -p 12300 -r

After the connection is successful, the system prompts me to change the password when run the SQL statement:

**Please use "ALTER ROLE "user" PASSWORD 'password';" to set the password of the user before other operations!**

My question is how to avoid changing the password after each installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifies the password of the database administrator by running commands during the running of gs_initdb, and the first step can be changed to

step1': gs_initdb -D /data2/openGauss/install --nodename='datanode' -w 'YourPassword~'